# Class method triggered after loading and not working after

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm moving a project to ES6 using Webpack with Babel to compile the code. Here is what I have right now:

entry.js

```
import Header from './components/header';

(function() {
  const header = new Header();
})();
```

header.js

```
export default class Header {
  constructor() {
    this.bodyTag = document.querySelector('body');
    this.toggleNavigationButton = document.querySelector('#toggleNavigationButton');

    this.toggleNavigationButton.addEventListener('click', this.toggleMobileNavigation());
  }

  toggleMobileNavigation() {
    this.bodyTag.classList.toggle('CLICK');
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./js/entry.js",
  output: {
      filename: "./js/bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['env']
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          { loader: "style-loader" },
          { loader: "css-loader" },
          { loader: "sass-loader" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
};
```

And the issue is, when the page load, the method is `toggleMobileNavigation` is triggered and the `click` event does not work at all.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your callback has parentheses and is then immediately invoked, try to remove them:

```
 this.toggleNavigationButton.addEventListener('click', this.toggleMobileNavigation);
```

Comment: Oh, OK, indeed. Thanks :) But what if I want to pass arguments to this callback?

Comment: ...('click', (e) => this.myMethod(arg1, arg2))

Comment: That totaly does it. Thanks again :)